# What are the purpose of the extra diodes in this peak detector circuit (LM1815)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, analog, texas-instruments

This is the circuit diagram from the [LM1815 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1815.pdf). I understand everything in this circuit except for the two diodes that I have marked with red. They are in a peak-detector circuit, but all of the implementations of peak detectors circuits that I am aware of only use a single diode. I tried adding them to a LT spice simulation but their effect on the output was insignificant.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual (but probably still a bit simplified) circuit has no diodes, but a Darlington-ish pair Q23 and Q24 and the other lone "diode" is Q20, Q21 and dual collector transistor Q22.

[image]

The Darlington pair is to reduce the loading on the peak detector capacitor.

Comment: I was going to remark that the two series diodes seem to provide only a positive-going path to the inverting and non-inverting inputs of two op-amps, which would mean that the voltage would never return to zero or any known point, due to capacitance. Although actual diodes and op-amps have finite leakage, eventually the voltage would stabilize, but the value and time would be undefined. But your more complete schematic shows a well defined path through Q23, R6, and R7.

Comment: @PStechPaul Yes, without the schematic it's a mystery, compounded by the *negative* 200nA bias current at the signal input current (current flowing out of the two 'op-amp' inputs). If was symmetrical like ordinary op-amps we'd expect the diodes to be reverse biased and the op-amps railed. I assume they're showing the diodes so if the user measures the voltage at pin 7 they get something they understand relative to the input voltage.

Answer (score 3):

You’re looking at a block diagram: it is a somewhat abstract depiction of what is going on.  The diodes on the block diagram are not literal components. They are blocks, just as the rest of the diagram. They represent a circuit that has two diode drops and conducts in one direction only. The implementation doesn’t have to use diodes.

The op-amps on the block diagram
may not be literal op-amps. They can be application-specific gain stages with negative feedback. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

To understand from the block diagram the purpose of the diodes for the zero crossing and peak detector, consider this:

- The peak detector has a decay resistor referenced to 0V (gnd)
- the differential inputs will then be 1 diode drop from 0V.
- this also means the signal input will be active in the region above 1 diode drop below ground
- elsewhere the signal input is clamped above and below ground to limit the range further but the transition of importance is observed as "just" above -0.5V for a low diode current voltage.

[image]

Now the "Theory of Operation" in the datasheet ought to make more sense.

How it is done is less important unless you like the nitty-gritty of how to design all these blocks in the diagram with the fewest number of transistors and be reliable.